# Error sequelize " is not associated to"

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs, sequelize.js

estoy intentando obtener los datos de una tabla y concatenar el contenido de otra (en realidad necesito concatenar varias) pero siempre obtengo el mismo error.

**EagerLoadingError [SequelizeEagerLoadingError]: Airplane is not associated to Flight!**

Estoy utilizando una base de datos MySQL de solo escritura que no fue creada por mi, puedo obtener resultados de cada tabla individual sin problemas.
He utilizado esta forma de relacionar las tablas muchas veces pero no se cual podrá ser el problema. Ya hice todo tipo de cambios en los modelos, intente sacar las relaciones del archivo de configuracion de la base de datos y ponerlo directamente en el modelo. Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

**Configuracion de la conexion a DB**

```js
require("dotenv").config();
const { Sequelize } = require("sequelize");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const { DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_HOST } = process.env;

const sequelize = new Sequelize(`${DB_NAME}`, `${DB_USER}`, `${DB_PASSWORD}`, {
  host: `${DB_HOST}`,
  dialect: "mysql",
  keepAlive:true
});

sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Conexion exitosa");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });

const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const modelDefiners = [];

fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, "/models"))
  .filter(
    (file) =>
      file.indexOf(".") !== 0 && file !== basename && file.slice(-3) === ".js"
  )
  .forEach((file) => {
    modelDefiners.push(require(path.join(__dirname, "/models", file)));
  });

modelDefiners.forEach((model) => model(sequelize));

let entries = Object.entries(sequelize.models);
let capsEntries = entries.map((entry) => [
  entry[0][0].toUpperCase() + entry[0].slice(1),
  entry[1],
]);

sequelize.models = Object.fromEntries(capsEntries);


const { Purchase, Passenger, Seat_type, Seat, Flight, Airplane, Boarding_pass } = sequelize.models;

 
Boarding_pass.belongsTo(Purchase, { foreignKey: 'purchase_id' });
Purchase.hasMany(Boarding_pass, { foreignKey: 'purchase_id' });


Boarding_pass.belongsTo(Passenger, { foreignKey: 'passenger_id' });
Passenger.hasMany(Boarding_pass, { foreignKey: 'passenger_id' });


Boarding_pass.belongsTo(Seat_type, { foreignKey: 'seat_type_id' });
Seat_type.hasMany(Boarding_pass, { foreignKey: 'seat_type_id' });

Boarding_pass.belongsTo(Seat, { foreignKey: 'seat_id' });
Seat.hasMany(Boarding_pass, { foreignKey: 'seat_id' });

Boarding_pass.belongsTo(Flight, { foreignKey: 'flight_id' });
Flight.hasMany(Boarding_pass, { foreignKey: 'flight_id' });

Seat.belongsTo(Seat_type, { foreignKey: 'seat_type_id' });
Seat_type.hasMany(Seat, { foreignKey: 'seat_type_id' });

Seat.belongsTo(Airplane, { foreignKey: 'airplane_id' });
Airplane.hasMany(Seat, { foreignKey: 'airplane_id' }); 

Flight.belongsTo(Airplane, { foreignKey: 'airplane_id' });
Airplane.hasMany(Flight, { foreignKey: 'airplane_id' }); 


module.exports = {
  ...sequelize.models,
  conn: sequelize, 
};
```

**Modelos**

```js
const { DataTypes } = require("sequelize");

module.exports = (sequelize) => {
    const Airplane= sequelize.define("airplane", {
       airplane_id: {
         type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
         allowNull: false,
         autoIncrement: true,
         primaryKey: true,
       },
       name: {
         type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
         allowNull: false,
       },
     },
     {
       timestamps: false,
       freezeTableName: true
     });
     return Airplane;
   };
```

```js
const { DataTypes } = require("sequelize");
const Airplane = require("./Airplane")

module.exports = (sequelize) => {
  const Flight = sequelize.define("flight", {
    flight_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    takeoff_date_time: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    takeoff_airport: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: false,
    },
    landing_date_time: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    landing_airport: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: false,
    },
    airplane_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    airplane_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false, 
        references: {
            model: Airplane,
            key: 'airplane_id',
          },
    }
  }, {
    timestamps: false,
    freezeTableName: true
  });

  return Flight;
};
```

**Ruta**

```js
const express = require("express");
const { conn } = require('../db');
const Flight = require('../models/Flight')(conn);
const Airplane = require('../models/Airplane')(conn)
const router = express.Router();


router.get('/:flight_id', async (req, res) => {
  const flight_id = req.params.flight_id;
  try {
    if(flight_id){
    const flight = await Flight.findAll({
      where: {
        flight_id
      },
       include: Airplane  
    });
      res.json(flight)

    } else {
      res.status(404).json({ message: 'No se encontró ningún registro con ese id.' });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    
    res.json(err);
  }
});
```